# What is a good book/online source about the subject of reliability?

Tags: probability, reference-request

I am particularly interested about

- Reliability function $R(t)$
- Failure function $h(t)$
- Renewal process
- Maintained systems
- Nonhomogenius Poisson process and reliability growth

Thank you.

Comment: A lot of this stuff is used in actuarial science, except the Reliability funciton is called the Survival function instead. *Actuarial Mathematics for Life Contingencies*, 2nd ed., by Dickson et al., is a standard text.

Comment: I'm closing since I think you'll have better luck in the stats SE.

Comment: These topics are not exclusive to actuarial science, but they are part of the stock in trade for operations research.  I think the material could well be on-topic here, but even for reference requests I would expect a narrower Question.  How do you hope to apply these tools?